# Django ModelChoiceField pre-filled with data?

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, field

I have a Django form called `Phase2Form` that has a `ModelChoiceField` called `purchase_order`. I would like to have a specific `purchase_order` already selected when the user goes to the form. I know how I would do this if it where a `CharField` or similar, but I don't know how to do this with a `ModelchoceField`. I will know the primary key for the ForeignKey `purchase_order` (it will be part of the URL).

I tried the following, which didn't work.

```
def escalate(request, po):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Phase2Form(request.POST, initial={'purchase_order': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=po) })
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/po/p2/')
    else: 
      return render(request, 'input.html', {'input_type': 'Phase 2', 'formset': form, 'error': True})
  else: 
    form = Phase2Form()
    return render(request, 'input.html', {'input_type': 'Phase 2','formset': form,})
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How is the URL pattern  that matches this view ?

Comment: @karthikr The relevant pattern is `url(r'^po/(\d+)/p2/$', escalate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your setting of purchase_order based on the url is in the request.POST condition which will only set when the form is posted.  Move the initial value setting down to the else condition.

```
  else: 
    form = Phase2Form(initial={'purchase_order': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=po) })
    return render(request, 'input.html', {'input_type': 'Phase 2','formset': form,})
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I don't have access to the project now. I'll try it in the morning, and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I've just been able to try your solution, it doesn't seem to have solved anything. `purchase_order` is still set to `---------` when I go to the page.

Comment: Oops. Never mind. works perfectly. I accidentally moved the `request.POST` term as well.